# TensorFlow tf.flag issue: FLAGS.__dict__['__flags'].items()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use the following commands in TensorFlow 1.5.0 and am receiving an unexpected error, considering I got this code off of Github and appeared to be working from everybody's feedback there. I suck at coding so I am presuming it is totally a stupid mistake

The first excerpt is `(file1==flow_trainv2.py):`

```
TRAIN_DIR = make_checkpoint_path(FLAGS.base_dir, FLAGS)
```

which calls on this excerpt in a separate file `(file2==experiment_manager.py):`

```
for k, v in FLAGS.__dict__['__flags'].items():
```

The error I receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "flow_trainv2.py", line 29, in <module>
    TRAIN_DIR = make_checkpoint_path(FLAGS.base_dir, FLAGS)
File "C:\...\experiment_manager.py", line 12, in make_checkpoint_path
    for k, v in FLAGS.__dict__['__flags'].items():
KeyError: '__flags'
```

I can run the 2nd file on it's own and it runs without error. So it is confusing to me that when I import the variable `make_checkpoint_path` from the first file, it returns the error above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FLAGS changed after 1.4

instead of:

```
for k, v in FLAGS.__dict__['__flags'].items():
```

you could do:

```
for k in FLAGS:
    v = FLAGS[k].value
```